# Issue in accessing API Session of a Server in C# format using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, api, request

Basically I am building a website with a given set of API from a company. From here, I am not allowed to access or alter the API given.

The API is given similar to the below's code

```
http://domainname.com/data.aspx?action=login
```

With that API, I was able to successfully return true or false with by doing a POST request with username and password.

Next, I am trying to get the details of the user with the similar given URL

```
http://domainname.com/data.aspx?action=user_details
```

In the above API, it is checking for Session["username"]. This is where my problem arises

From my side, I am using nodejs.

```
var request = require('request');

var postData = {
    'username': 'example',
    'userpass': 'abc123',
};

request.get({url:'http://domainname.com/data.aspx?action=login', formData:postData}, function(err,httpResponse,body1){ 
    console.log(body1);
    request.get({url:'http://domainname.com/data.aspx?action=user_details'}, function(err,httpResponse,body2){ 
        console.log(body2);
    })
})
```

The first console.log of body1 resulted : true

The second console.log of body2 resulted: [] (empty array)

To make sure that the API is working fine, I used [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/) extension of Google Chrome. First, I log in the user, and run the user_details API and from there it returns the details of the user.

What am I missing from my end?

Comment: Maybe they keep user data in a cookie. So it's work with postman but not with request. Can you check it?

Comment: @Ygalbel, I have checked the cookie of POSTMAN using the user_details API. It doesn't have any username in it

Comment: Do they keep in Cookie SessionId ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Asp.net keeps cookie called sessionId, 
so you have to enable cookie with "request".

> Cookieless SessionIDs By default, the SessionID value is stored in a
>   non-expiring session cookie in the browser. However, you can specify
>   that session identifiers should not be stored in a cookie by setting
>   the cookieless attribute to true in the sessionState section of the
>   Web.config file.

As said in [Request](https://github.com/request/request) documentation,
Cookies are disabled by default.

That's a quote from their documentation:

> Cookies are disabled by default (else, they would be used in
>   subsequent requests). To enable cookies, set jar to true (either in
>   defaults or options).
>
> ```
> var request = request.defaults({jar: true})
> request('http://www.google.com', function () {  
> request('http://images.google.com') })
> ```

With cookies enabled it will work you like postman and chrome.

Comment: Oh! I should have checked on that. Ygalbel, you're a life saver. Thank you! It works now.